# Custom Contact data in XML or database for application?

Tags: android, xml, database, android-contacts

Writing my first Android app. Thought I would start with a Corporate Directory application. The app will only have read access to the data (for searching/displaying).

The data will have to be extracted from Active Directory.

So I have a few questions.

Should I put the data in xml or a database. I'm leaning towards xml.

Would it be possible to create a custom contact database and use that instead? It would seem to me to be easier to just create a custom contact database and then the application could just leverage all of the built contact functionality just pointing to a different database.

Any other tips would also be appreciated.

thanks,

lee

Comment: if you just need to display/search contacts it sounds pointless to me to create custom database. You need to read the original database anyway to create the custom database. Also, working with the contacts is almost like working with normal sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brother ! Nice question !

I am suggesting you to use **Database** in case of xml file !

No doubt xml is light weight and easy to use compare to database. But in your case you want to add functionality of custom contacts. If you make xml and fetch data from this, no metter. Its possible ! But incase ( I said incase) you need to add/remove one or more field then ? you have to modify the whole xml file ! But in case of database just enter/remove that field ! ! No need to modify whole database ! Hope you understand my review ! Thank you